# Approximate a Riemann integrable function by a Riemann integrable simple function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, riemann-integration

For a given Riemann integrable function $f$ on $[a,b]$ and $\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$, is there a Riemann integrable simple function $g$ such that $|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon, \ x \in [a,b]$?

It is readily to find a simple function to approximate $f$, but it seems hard to prove such a simple function Riemann integrable. Actually, I do not think it is Riemann integrable.

However, it is also hard to find a counterexample.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know simple functions are always Riemann integrable. The problem would be that $\int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)| dx < \epsilon$ does not imply that for all $x\in[a,b]$, $|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$. I suspect a counterexample could be $f$ which is zero everywhere except for $f(x_n)=1$ along a sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $a$.